# Making range output responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so the problem I'm having is making the output for the range responsive.

It's currently working fine when you run the code because the value is being position in pixels, but when you resize the viewport is doesn't align with the slider thumb correctly. I thought maybe aligning the output using percentages instead of pixels might fix the problem but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly.

I have tried messing around with it but no luck, does anyone know how I can achieve this?

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <div class="range-control" data-thumbwidth="20">
        <input id="inputRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
            <div><output name="rangeVal">0</output></div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

**CSS:**

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

form {
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.range-control {
    position: relative;
}

input[type=range] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    position: relative;
    height: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

output {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    margin-left: -15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #777;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=range]:active + output {
    display: block;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.range-control').each(function(){
    var container = $(this),
        input = container.find('input'),
        output = container.find('output'),
        rangeWidth = input.width(),
        thumbWidth = container.attr('data-thumbwidth'),
        startValue = input.val(),
        startOffset = ((rangeWidth - thumbWidth) / 100) * startValue + '%';

    output
        .css({
            'left' : startOffset
        });

    $(input).on('input', function(){
        var value = this.value,
            offset = ((rangeWidth - thumbWidth) / 100) * value;

    output
        .val(value)
        .css({
            'left' : offset
        });

    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkt3e2qL)**

Any help would be appreciated greatly!!!

** **EDIT** ** Please Read

So below Mohamed-Yousef answered the question in the way he would do it which does work, so I have up voted it, however he has duplicated the variables twice in the code (see his answer for details about this). I think there is a more efficient way of doing this (using less code), so if anyone has a better way of doing this please share.

Answer (score 5):

simply you need to update your variable on window resize to change its values .. and make your input event inside each function print it more than one time and that make it not available to read a new variable after resize .. so I take it out and run each event individual

**AFTER EDIT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container,input,output,rangeWidth,thumbWidth,startValue,startOffset;
    // make a function to update variable
    var update_variable = function(){
        $('.range-control').each(function(){
            container = $(this);
            input = container.find('input');
            output = container.find('output');
            rangeWidth = input.width();
            thumbWidth = container.attr('data-thumbwidth');
            startValue = input.val();
            startOffset = ((rangeWidth - thumbWidth) / 100) * startValue;

        output
            .css({
                'left' : startOffset
            });

        });   
    }
    // update variable after document ready
    update_variable();

    // input input event
    $('.range-control > input').on('input', function(){
            var value = this.value,
                offset = ((rangeWidth - thumbWidth) / 100) * value;

        $(this).closest('.range-control').find('output')
            .val(value +'%')
            .css({
                'left' : offset
            });
        });
    // update variable in window resize
    $(window).on('resize',update_variable);  
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkt3e2qL/14/)

**Important Note:** this code will work perfect if you have inputs with the same width .. if its not the same width you need to use an array of elements to get each element width

Comment: Thanks for the response Mohamed! So the way I was trying to do it with percentages, would that not work?

Comment: @Jordan if you have more than one input take a look at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lkt3e2qL/7/

Comment: Oh sorry, I've only just seen your comment, yeah that's great. Take a look at this fiddle, the output isn't resizing properly. http://jsfiddle.net/Lkt3e2qL/8/

Comment: Also is the the most efficient way of doing this? It looks like a lot of extra code for what it's purpose is.

Comment: @Jordan updated answer .. there is no more code man .. I explain that in answer .. you need window resize event to update your variables that is it

Comment: Yeah that seems to be working a lot better, is there a better way of using the window resize without having to rewrite the variables twice in the code?

Comment: @Jordan this code will work perfect if you have inputs with the same width .. if its not the same width you need to use an array of elements to get each element width .. about variable twice I don't know really but I used to make a variable twice .. if its just action I using functions .. but with variables this is my way .. Good Luck to you :)